# javascript eval drops everything after question mark

Tags: javascript

I'm definitely still learning Javascript so please forgive me if this is a very basic question.

I am attempting to rotate through a list of image URLs into an href.  All of the URLs have question marks in them as the URLs are being passed to Web Services to detail specifics vars about the image.  In the header I have broken out the php $imgArr into separate javascript Image object .src values.  Everything is working fine to this point.

Image URL Ex: `http://webservices.ashx?size=25`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var step = 1;
var timeOut;

function playforward() {
    if (!document.images) return
    alert(eval("image" + step + ".src"));
    document.images.slideleft.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
    if (step < <?php echo count($imgArr); ?> ) step++
    else step = 1
    timeOut = setTimeout("playforward()", 500)
}

function stopPlay() {
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
}
//-->
</script>
```

In the code above I have an alert of the base image name with the step variable that cycles through the image numbers.  When the alert box pops up the image URL is correct, but when I take out the alert box and run the page the image errors out and the properties show that everything after the question mark is dropped.

I know enough to realize that eval is not a great solution but I don't know a better one.  Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT:

As per request here is the code I am using to create the image variables.  This code is being called in the Codeigniter Controller and passed to the document header.  I do not believe it will be a great deal of help but here it is:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($imgArr); $i++)
    {
     $urlPieces = explode('?', $imgArr[$i]);
     $num = $i+1;
     $images .= 'var image'. $num .'=new Image()
       imageleft'. $num .'.src="'.$urlPieces[0].'" + "?" + "'.$urlPieces[1].'"; ';
    }
```

Comment: You don't need the `<!--` and `//-->` anymore.

Comment: What is `image1`, `image2`, etc.?  Are those variables, images, what are they?

Comment: Why are you using eval to add a string together? Who taught you that?

Comment: @epascarello: The `eval` is being used to get the `.src` attribute from a variable like `image1`.

Comment: image1 image2 is stuff like http://webservices.ashx?location=stuff&size=25 so all of them have a question mark in them.  Thanks for the hint about taking out the comment stuff.

Comment: @jessier3: So they are strings?  Objects?  DOM Elements (images)?

Comment: Show that code that the eval is grabbing the source from. There is better ways of referencing images.

Comment: P.S. `setTimeout("playforward()", 500)` should really be: `setTimeout(playforward, 500)`.  Passing strings uses `eval`, pass functions.

Comment: could you post an example of image1? is it something like `var image1 = {src: "webservices.ashx?location=stuff&size=25"};`?

Comment: The images are strings. An actual example of the images is: http://localhost/ImageViewHTTPHandler/GetImage.ashx?packagepath=c:\packages\insp\somezipfile.zip&entryname=snapshot-front2-full.jpg&scalepercent=50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason you should be using `eval` in your code at all.

That said `<? php ...` should be `<?php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var step = 1;
    var timeOut;

    function playforward() {
        if (!document.images) {
            return;
        }

        alert(window['image' + step].src);
        document.images.slideleft.src = window['image' + step].src;

        if (step < <?php echo count($imgArr); ?> ) {
           step++;
        } else {
           step = 1;
        }

        timeOut = setTimeout(playforward, 500);
    }

    function stopPlay() {
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can't just remove `eval` like that. `"image" + step + ".src"` is not the same as `eval("image" + step + ".src")`.

Comment: Yeah, the space was added when I pasted it in for some reason.  It's not in the original code.  I'm all over not using eval.  What do I use instead?  When I just drop eval it just uses image1.src as the image link instead of the value of the var.

Comment: Hey JaredMcAteer,  Thank you so much for the code but I'm getting an error when I use it.  It is saying that the var image is undefined.  That is correct, that image is undefined because the image var name is image1, image2, etc.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer: It should be `window['image' + step]`, not `window[image + step]` :-P

Comment: @jessier3: I fixed a typo in the answer, try it now :-P

Answer (score 0):

You have variables like `image1`, `image2`, etc.

Instead  of that, make `images` into an array:

```
var images = [];
```

So, then you can do:

```php
$images .= 'images['. $num .']=new Image()'
```

Then in your JavaScript, you can use:

```
images[step].src
```

P.S. Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, pass functions:

```
setTimeout(playforward, 500)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.  It does not throw an error but it has the same problem as the original code.  The alert comes up with the full URL but when I pull the alert out and run the code the image errors and the properties shows everything past the question mark was dropped.

Comment: Try to `alert(document.images.slideleft.src)` after you set it, to make sure the URL is being set.  Are you sure the URL is correct?